# CSS3 Transition (cubic-bezier) is not working in Firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-transitions

```
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1) 0;
```

It is supported according to w3schools.

Works fine in Chrome, IE and Opera.

http://jsfiddle.net/FSEqT/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oddly not including the unit of seconds in the [`transition-delay`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-delay) property causes the transition to not work. Just change your `transition` rule to:

```
transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1) 0s;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FSEqT/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
-moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/timing-function

Comment: I believe the -moz prefix is deprecated.

Comment: `-moz-transition` is still a valid property. You can check deprecated properties [here ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions)